# Extend Dictionary and create instance from other dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am extending the C# Dictionary class:

```
class Table<TA> : Dictionary<Int, TA> {}
```

But now I have a dictionary, and I want to create a Table out of it. I tried:

```
Dictionary<Int, Int> myDico = ... // somewhere else
Table<Int> myTable = new Table{ myDico };
```

But this complains with,

> "Table does not contain a constructor accepting this argument."

I come from a java/scala background and because C# does not have type aliases, it is the only way I found I could use aliases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just create a constructor that accepts a dictionary, and pass it to the base constructor:

```
class Table<TA> : Dictionary<Int, TA>
{
    public Table(IDictionary<Int, TA> dictionary)
        : base(dictionary)
    {
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Dictionary<Int, Int> myDico = ... // somewhere else
Table<Int> myTable = new Table(myDico);
```

Comment: That sounds great. It was hard to find this base constructor. Does it create a new structure with a variable pointing to the dictonary in it or are the two types Table and Dictionary aliases in that case?

Comment: @MikaëlMayer, it creates a new dictionary with the same items as the original (so it's a copy, not a wrapper)